# uuencode attaches file at the beginning of the mail body

Tags: email-attachments, aix, uuencode

I am using below code in AIX and the problem is it attaches the file at the very beginning of the mail, I want to attach the file after the mail body.

```
(uuencode <filepath> <filename-in-mail>;cat <body-of-the-mail-file>) | mailx -s "Subject" -r <sender-address> <multiple-receiver-addresses>
```

Any thoughts?, On AIX only uuencode is working, base64 or any other command doesn't work.

I tried a lame change in the code `uuencode cat <body-of-the-mail-file>;<filepath> <filename-in-mail>` but it gave error

Comment: Please quote complete scripts, also quote the error messages.

Comment: @ZsigmondLőrinczy It's uuencode command which i need to check, my ask is in uuencode the file I attach shows at the beginning of the body of email where as I want to show the body of email which is simply a file and post that the file attached should be visible.